# Удаление наименьшего из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

> Введите текст из нескольких слов. Определите самое короткое слово и удалите его из текста. Если слов несколько, удалите их все.

Программа должна запрашивать ввод слов через `input().split()` (но пока заменил списком):

```py
spisok = ['as', 'sa', 'ad', 'qwer', 'qwerty', 'fgjhdty', 'hi', 'bvnv']
print(spisok)
dl = len(spisok)
dlina_stroki = 100
for i in range(dl):
    j = min(spisok)
    if len(j) < dlina_stroki:
        minimum = min(j)
        spisok.remove(j)
        print(j)
print(spisok)
```

Помогите с решением данного вопроса?

Comment: покажите, что уже пробовали делать.

Comment: Показывай что сделал, с чем сложности возникли.

Comment: [Добавляйте всё в вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1073916/edit), не надо писать комментариев.

Comment: Предлагаю отсортировать (O(N * log N) и потом убрать первые равные элементы, или последние, в зависимости от направленности. (O(N)).
Суммарная: O(N * log N) + O(N) = O(N * log N)

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю отфильтровать список, использовав в качестве условия длину наименьшего элемента. Сложность `О(N)`.

***Пример:***

```py
words = ['as', 'sa', 'ad', 'qwer', 'qwerty', 'fgjhdty', 'hi', 'bvnv']
shortest_word_len = len(min(words, key=len))

result = [s for s in words if len(s) > shortest_word_len]
print(result)
```

***stdout:***

```py
['qwer', 'qwerty', 'fgjhdty', 'bvnv']
```

Comment: `min(words, key=len)`, у вас же сейчас лексикографический порядок сравнения. `words.append('b'); print(min(words))  # -> 'ad'`

Comment: @mkkik Да, Вы правы. Спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['as', 'sa', 'ad', 'qwer', 'qwerty', 'fgjhdty', 'hi', 'bvnv']
shortest = min(map(len, words))

index = -1
for word in words[::-1]:
    if len(word) == shortest:
        words.pop(index)
    else:
        index -= 1

print(words)  // ['qwer', 'qwerty', 'fgjhdty', 'bvnv']
```

Comment: Буду разбираться. Спасибо!